# How can I use Google Cloud Messaging with Django

Tags: django, push-notification

I am trying to use google cloud messaging with django. I found `https://github.com/geeknam/python-gcm` on git but am not sure how to really use it. However I was wondering if there was any other app for this, perhaps `django-gcm` with documentation on how to use it. help??

Comment: What specific help do you need with django-gcm? You include the app under INSTALLED_APPS. You provide your GCM API key and it takes care of the rest...?

Answer (score 4):

you can use django-gcm. It would solve your problem. Just follow the Documentation and you are good to go.

Things you need to do before using Django-gcm.

1. go to https://console.developers.google.com
2. then create your project using the above header, when your project gets created you would be redirected to that project page, now Note down the `Project Name` and `Project ID`, `Project ID` would be used as a `Sender ID` from your Android app.
3. Now click `Enable and Manage APIs`, now choose `Cloud Messaging from Android` from `Mobile APIs` section.
4. Now you would be able to see `Enable API` button, click on that and you would be able to see `Go to Credentials` section, and you would be redirected to the next page.
5. Now in `Where will you be calling the API from?` option choose `Web Server` and click on `what credentials do I need ?`.
6. From the side bar select Credentials, and then click on `New Credentials`. Select Name for your Key and Leave the IP address text box blank and hit create, and Now note down this Key this would be used as your GCM_APIKEY in your Django Application.

Now you can follow the django-gcm documentation to setup GCM from this link

[django-gcm documentation](http://django-gcm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html)

Also, When you reach at [django-gcm sending messages](http://django-gcm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sending_messages.html), Please note that the message body might send `Null` messages at your Android Device. So I have recently made a change to the Documentation please refer to this.

[django-gcm recent documentation changes](https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm/pull/40)

If you also get issues with Android app you can refer to this link and find a client app using GCM service.
[django-gcm sample client](https://github.com/bogdal/pager)

Answer (score 1):

I used teh following:

https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm

It was very well designed and I was able to get it to work out of the box. One small change I made is that I added the following to the `Device` model:

```
users = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', null=True, blank=True, related_name='android_devices')
```

This allows the device to be mapped to a set of users.

One thing to notice is that this app does **not** handle responses from the GCM server. Which is something that has to be added. Refer to this page:

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#reg-state

Things such as updated `registration_id`'s and `NotRegistered` messages (when a user no longer has your app) are to be handled. It's very trivial to add, but should be done.

Comment: Did you derive a new model from one of django-gcm's models or is this for your own model?  Would be nice if you added some context for this one liner...

Comment: I just updated the `AbstractDevice` model and included the above many to many field. I included the GCM app with source in my application, rather than doing a pip install, and customized it for my needs.